# How to implement a lag feature in an ARIMA model

Tags: python, time-series

I understand how to create a lag feature and how it can be helpful, but I don't understand is how to implement it in the training/testing phase.

Currently I shift the data 1 spot and that creates another column. At this point I have an index which is my time and two columns. One with the original data and another that has been shifted.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opIhe.png)

I then remove the first row as to get rid of the NaN value.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM9LD.png)
However when I then train on that dataset do that I get an error stating I can only run a data frame as a 1d array.
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (14, 2) instead.

All of that to ask, how do I properly implement a lag feature?

The images are my dataframes.

As far as code goes:

```
df['shifted_entry_fee'] = df['entry_fee'].shift(3)

df = df.drop(df.index[0:3])

#if I don't drop the original entry_fee column the i get this 
error

model = ARMA(train_data, order=(1,0,0))

ValueError: endog is required to have ndim 1 but has ndim 2
```

Comment: Hi Grant, please provide a small example of your DataFrame, what you've tried, and what you're expecting the results to be. Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you need an example on how to do that.

Comment: Thank you for that advice. I updated with code and mentioned that the images are my dataframes!

Comment: @Simon it's been updated!